# Cannot use 2 Finagle Services on a single server using the ThriftServerFramedCodec

Tags: thrift, finagle

I'm getting started with finagle using version 6.6.2, and version 3.8.0 of the scrooge-maven-plugin

I have multiple services defined and have successfully tested them individually.

```
ServerBuilder().bindTo(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 9090)).name("myFinagle").codec(ThriftServerFramedCodec()).build(myFinagleService)
```

but I am having trouble getting 2 services to run on a single port.  I found

ThriftMuxServer.serverIface

but this seems to start the server right away, and does not allow me to add another IFace.

How do I bind 2 services to a single server port?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finagle currently (latest=6.13.1) doesn't support binding two thrift interfaces on the same address.